# HTML list drill down on JSON array with CSS target selector

Tags: html, css, json

In my html file I have a list that I build dynamically from JSON array.
I display in each list item only one field of each object (the title).
I want to do a drill down when I click on a list item.
I saw this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/170049/Pure-HTML-5-CSS-3-Modal-Dialog-Box-no-JavaScript) where the dialog implemented without javascript.

How can I pass the index of the JSON object from the array with css `:target` or in some othe way?
(The purpose is to show a dialog with all object field)

Comment: Please add some relevant code of attempted solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put in your html not only the "title" field, but also some Id or any unique field in a hidden input. So you could get it with "onclick" and get the object from JSON.

Comment: I did that, I asked if it possible to do it with css :target selector

Answer (score 1):

If you're determined to use the `:target` selector, would something like this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/auFX3/

Though if you're already generating this list from a JSON object, I'm not sure why you're against @Baseleus' [javascript-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253772).  It would really help us out if you could post some code to show what you've already tried.

Comment: I'm just asking if it possible to pass parameters with target selector?

Comment: Ok, but your question is not clear. What do you expect to pass the parameter to? What are you going to do with that parameter? You've gotten two answers, neither of which is what you're looking for. That should be a clue that the question as phrased is not clear to most readers.  If you can provide us with some _commented_ code that shows what you're attempting to do, how you expected it to turn out, and how reality differed from your expectations, you'll likely get an acceptable answer a lot faster.